# How can I get YouTube urls programmatically?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get YouTube url's programmatically  and trying to create a download button on YouTube. I'm following a tutorial project which says use

```
'ytplayer.config.args.url_encoded_fmt_stream.map.split(",");'
```

I run this directly in the console and have tried running it through my project, but I keep getting

```
VM765:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
at <anonymous>:1:45'
```

A couple posts on stack overflow talk about using this same line, but I'm not sure why it's not working.

**manifest.json**

```
"name" : "Simple Youtube Downloader", 
"description" : "Download youtube videos simpler than before. ",
"version" : "0.1",
"author" : "Nick Germaine",
"web_accessible_resources" : ["src/youtubedl.js"],
"manifest_version" : 2,
"content_scripts" : [
    {
        "matches" : ["https://www.youtube.com/watch*"],
        "js" : ["src/loader.js"]
    }
]
```

**loader.js**

```
s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("src/youtubedl.js");

s.onload = function(){
    this.remove();
}

document.head.appendChild(s);
```

**youtubedl.js**

```
var videoUrls = window.ytplayer.config.args.loaderUrl.map.split(',');



console.log("our extension has loaded", videoUrls)
```

Comment: Youtube is a fairly complex app, and it's possible things have changed since the tutorial you're following was created. If you want more help it would be useful to have more detail around what you're trying to do, and a larger body of relevant code.

Comment: I am attempting to get the direct url's from YouTube so I can create a download button on the YouTube page when I watch a video. I'll go ahead and add some more of my files

Answer (score 0):

the error indicates that `url_encoded_fmt_stream` is undefined. you might be able to get more help on this if you post a complete code example.

Answer (score 0):

A few points,

1. It turns out downloading YouTube videos is against their policy, so if you're trying to publish an extension or anything like that it is likely going to get taken down.
2. YouTube changes their site fairly regularly so any tutorial you might be looking at is probably outdated. I inspected that element you are referring to in your code and it is just an empty object which is why you're getting undefined when you try to run a map function.
3. If you are still interested in building this tool I would suggest looking at this GitHub repo. It looks like a fairly robust solution to accomplishing what you are trying to do, and they expose an API so you could wrap it in an extension or whatever https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core

Comment: Ah ok, so you are saying they may have changed this policy and now it's much more difficult to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not trying to publish it, I just want to make it as a tutorial project